# How to add declaration of array in Class JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need help with this simple code , i need to declare the numbers array inside the class List so that  all the methods can use it from inside.

```
let numbers  = [];

class List {
    add(number) {
        numbers.push(number);
    }
    get(number) {
        let index = numbers[number];
        return index;
    }
    remove(index) {
        numbers.splice(index, 1);
    }
    size() {
        return numbers.length;
    }
}

let list = new List();
list.add(5);
list.add(6);
list.add(7);
console.log(list.get(1));
list.remove(1);
console.log(list.get(1));
```

Comment: Use class `constructor` and inside the `constructor` function declare the number array like: `this.numbers = [];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the array in the `constructor` and access it in the other methods using `this`. Here is the updated code:

```js
class List {
     constructor(){
          this.numbers = [];
     }
     add(number) {
          this.numbers.push(number);
     }
     get(number) {
          let index = this.numbers[number];
          return index;
     }
     remove(index) {
          this.numbers.splice(index, 1);
     }
     size() {
          return this.numbers.length;
     }
}
let list = new List();
list.add(5);
list.add(6);
list.add(7);
console.log(list.get(1));
list.remove(1);
console.log(list.get(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting something like this:

```js
class List {
 constructor() {
  this.numbers = [];
 }
 
 add(number) {
  this.numbers.push(number);
 }
 
 getIndex(number) {
  return this.numbers.findIndex(item => item === number);
 }
 
 remove(number) {
  this.numbers = this.numbers.filter(item => item !== number);
 }
 
 removeByIndex(index) {
  this.numbers.splice(index, 1);
 }
 
 showNumbers() {
  return this.numbers;
 }
}

let list = new List();
list.add(5);
list.add(6);
list.add(7);
list.add(8);

console.log(list.showNumbers());
list.remove(7);
console.log(list.showNumbers());
list.removeByIndex(list.getIndex(8));
console.log(list.showNumbers());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```